# Given index matrix and raw data , how to reconstruct new dataframe quickly

Tags: python

I have a data frame and a table of index corresponding to the data frame. To create a new data frame, is there any other way to reconstruct the new data. The row index in the index table is actually the row number, so in python sense, the actual row index =row number-1.

```
    # simulate index table
    col_index=np.random.choice([0,1], 5, p=[0.4, 0.6])
    row_index=np.random.choice([3,1,2],5, p=[0.4, 0.5,0.1])
    ind=np.vstack((row_index,col_index))
    ind=ind.T

    array([[3, 0],
   [3, 1],
   [2, 1],
   [1, 1],
   [1, 0]])

    dt=np.random.random((5, 2)) #simulated data

    array([[ 0.3592,  0.4983],
       [ 0.0518,  0.2291],
       [ 0.4322,  0.5654],
       [ 0.8482,  0.1722],
       [ 0.1448,  0.5766]])

    # My code
    newDt=np.zeros([5,1])
    for j in range(5):
        row=ind[j,0]
        col=ind[j,1]
        newDt[j]=dt[row-1,col]

    #output
    array([[ 0.4322],
       [ 0.5654],
       [ 0.2291],
       [ 0.4983],
       [ 0.3592]])
```

Comment: .... what? You say you want a dataframe but your output is an array...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what I mean is i need a series of values corresponding to the index table. Think of it as looking up the table and record each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have some values, `vals`, and some indices, `ind`:

```
>>> vals
array([[ 0.3592,  0.4983],
       [ 0.0518,  0.2291],
       [ 0.4322,  0.5654],
       [ 0.8482,  0.1722],
       [ 0.1448,  0.5766]])
>>> ind
array([[3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

The easiest way to get what you want is to use multidimensional indexing:

```
>>> vals[ind[:,0] - 1, ind[:,1]]
array([ 0.4322,  0.5654,  0.2291,  0.4983,  0.3592])
```

If, as your question seems to imply, your values are in a `pd.DataFrame`, then you can access the `values` attribute to work with the underlying `np.array`:

```
>>> df
        0       1
0  0.3592  0.4983
1  0.0518  0.2291
2  0.4322  0.5654
3  0.8482  0.1722
4  0.1448  0.5766
>>> df.values[ind[:,0] - 1, ind[:,1]]
array([ 0.4322,  0.5654,  0.2291,  0.4983,  0.3592])
```

Comment: What if the "table"  is more than three dimensions, and the "data" to be index is also more than three dimensions?  Is there a way to express data for more than three dimensions without loops?

Comment: @alphabetagamma it should work the same way with higher dimensions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comments. For example, for a dynamic programming problems, you might have more than state variables, for each state variables, you have a associated value tables,  The table is just a plane, what if you have a three-dimensional space or even higher dimensions

Comment: @alphabetagamma what? This sounds like it has nothing to do with your question. Why don't you ask the question you are actually trying to answer. And please use standard terminology. You keep using terms like "dataframe" and "table" but you probably just mean "array". I don't know, because you haven't been consistent. In any event, indexing into higher dimensional arrays works *exactly the same* as I've show in this answer.